# Consecutive number of theorems, propositions, etc

Tags: numbering, theorems

I'm using

```
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
```

The numberings of Theorem and Proposition are not consecutive (I get Theorem 1 followed by Proposition 1 instead of Theorem 1 followed by Proposition 2). How can I fix it?

I need this numbering because otherwise I would have Theorem 1, Proposition 1, Lemma 1, Corollary 1, Remark 1, etc. which I think is very confusing if I reference Proposition 1 later.

Comment: Why you need that numbering? LaTeX and its packages are usually made ​​for standard document composition.

Comment: @osjerick Please see my edit.

Comment: several variations on the numbering of theorem-class objects, including this one, are covered in the user's guide: `texdoc amsthm`.

Comment: You helped me do the opposite (consecutive to non-consecutive). So, here goes the upvote! :-P

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `\newtheorem` construction offers two optional arguments. The first one fixes your numbering. In this case it means that `proposition` should use the same counter as `theorem`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\begin{document}


\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}

\begin{theorem}
1+1=2.
\end{theorem}

\begin{proposition}
1+2=3
\end{proposition}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh I see, thanks. So if I want `remark` to use the same numbering as `theorem`, `proposition`, and `corollary`, do I put `\newtheorem{theorem,proposition,corollary}[remark]{Remark}`?

Comment: @Kunal Rather one by one. If the main is `theorem`, then `\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}` and so on.