# different types of exercises, theorems etc

Tags: numbering, theorems, exercises

I need to categorize theorems like **School Book Theorem**, **Important Theorem**, **Interesting Theorem** etc with different numbering. The same at the exercises.

How can I do it?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It would be great if you could  show us what you have tried. Posting a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that indicates what you are trying to do makes it easier for people to understand what you want. It also makes it easier for people to help you, since they have some code to start from, and hence much more likely that some one will try to help you.

Comment: You are right. I fixed it!

Comment: @ΚώσταςΚούδας please click on the link above and see what a Minimal Working Example is.

Comment: Try searching TeX.SX for `\newtheorem`.... For example, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144535/consecutive-number-of-theorems-propositions-etc?rq=1

Comment: Excellent! That's I was looking for! It's so simple that I feel stupid! Thank's a lot!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because solved in comment (the user found the solution by himself after knowing which macro to use)

Comment: I agree that question has to close,  but I don't know how to do it...